# Python RegEx: Not capturing all the data (python3.6, scrapy)

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I was trying to script a website of length information using the following simple code:

```
list = re.findall('(?<=Length:\s\s)[:\d]+', response.text)      
if len(list) > 0:            
    data['Length'] = list[0]        
else:            
    data['Length'] = '00:00'
```

However, it only gets the information if the length information is less than one hour. For example, it gets the 51:00 but not 01:08:47. I checked the source code for both shorter and longer than one hour. Here are how they look. It seems that for length more than 1 hour, there is one less white space. So I tried, but this time, list only returns a white space. Does anybody know how to get both short and long information? Thank you very much!

```
list = re.findall('(?<=Length:)[\s:\d]+', response.text)      
if len(list) > 0:            
    data['Length'] = list[0]        
else:            
    data['Length'] = '00:00'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How's this? https://regex101.com/r/8buref/1

Comment: i think your regex pattern is ok, even it will match others format string. can u show us text of response.text, instead of screenshot.

Comment: We can't test without the exact data.

Comment: Thank you very much, Yudong. This online tool is very helpful. I also wanted to comment that eventually, I did the following to remove the space out and make life easier:     a=response.text.replace(" ", "") 
list = re.findall('(?<=Length:)(\d\d[:\d\d]+)', a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `'(?<=Length:)\s*(\d\d[\s*:\s*\d\d]+)'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex and extract whatever is present in group 1:

```
Length\s*:\s*(\d+\s*(?::\s*\d+\s*){1,2})
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQvw2L/2)

**Explanation:**

- `Length\s*:` - matches `Length` literally followed by 0+ occurrences of a white-space, as many as possible
- `:\s*` - matches a `:` followed by 0+ white-spaces
- `\d+\s*` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit followed by 0+ white-spaces. We start capturing the text from here in Group 1. We capture until the end of the match.
- `(?::\s*\d+\s*){1,2}` - matches either 1 or 2 occurrences of the pattern `(?::\s*\d+\s*)`

  - `(?:)` - indicates a non-capturing group
  - `:\s*` - matches a `:` followed by 0+ occurrences of a white-space
  - `\d+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit
  - `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a white-space

**Alternative Regex:(without any group)**

[`(?<=Length:\s\s)\d+\s*(?::\s*\d+\s*){1,2}`](https://regex101.com/r/SQvw2L/3)